# Coolest jacket I ever had/ have ever had?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I bought a jacket today, and it is really cool, so I want to tell my friends.

- Which one of the following sentences is correct?
- Is there a difference between them?

> 1. It's the coolest jacket I **ever had**!
> 2. It's the coolest jacket I **have ever had**!

Comment: As a community, perhaps we should avoiding asking, "Which one of these is grammatically correct?" What makes you think one of these is right and the other is wrong? Both are fine; you can say it either way.

Comment: @J.R. Sorry sir for that... I don't know which one is right or wrong and this is why I asked. Also... I was hoping to know is there any different between them? Sorry I should add it in my question

Comment: I agree: _Is there any difference between them_ is a much more useful question to learners. Thanks for taking the time to edit and improve your question!

Answer (score 2):

The grammatically correct way is to use present perfect.

> It's the coolest jacket I have ever had!

When you use words like "never", "ever", "already", "yet", this usually requires present perfect tense.

Comment: Agreed. If you still possess the jacket, then its status as your coolest jacket is ongoing.  "Coolest jacket I ever had" would be how I reminisced about a jacket I no longer own.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your sentences are understandable, correct, and have the same meaning. However,

> It's the coolest jacket I ever had!

is more informal than

> It's the coolest jacket I have ever had!

When your friends see your jacket they may say

> That jacket is the coolest.
>   Your jacket is the coolest ever.
>   *Your jacket is the coolest I have ever seen*

Comment: Do you not think using "Had" indicates past if yes then how "It is the coolest jacket i ever had" is similar to "It is the coolest jacket i have ever had"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes more formal, but the context of “ever had”, would be assumed that you no longer possess said subject. Whereas “I have ever had” would imply you still maintain possession